# Create the table as same as excel format in plotly python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

How to create the table as same as my excel format in the plotly python?

In excel, using the index with match formula to display the data in my customize table.
formula in excel: index(column A, match(column B,column c, 0))

How the python coding for the similar formula?

[image]

Data:

Date Minor  Major   MTD

01/01/2022  Clutlery    Kitchen     1000

01/01/2022  Tops    Clothes     100

01/01/2022  Shoes   Clothes     200

01/01/2022  Turf    Garden  1

01/01/2022  Hoses   Garden  2

01/01/2022  Rakes   Garden  3

01/01/2022  Cooking     Kitchen     4

02/01/2022  Clutlery    Kitchen     2000

02/01/2022  Tops    Clothes     200

02/01/2022  Shoes   Clothes     400

02/01/2022  Turf    Garden  2

02/01/2022  Hoses   Garden  4

02/01/2022  Rakes   Garden  6

02/01/2022  Cooking     Kitchen     8

01/02/2022  Clutlery    Kitchen     200

01/02/2022  Tops    Clothes     300

01/02/2022  Shoes   Clothes     400

01/02/2022  Turf    Garden  5

01/02/2022  Hoses   Garden  6

01/02/2022  Rakes   Garden  7

01/02/2022  Cooking     Kitchen     8

02/02/2022  Clutlery    Kitchen     4000

02/02/2022  Tops    Clothes     400

02/02/2022  Shoes   Clothes     600

02/02/2022  Turf    Garden  800

02/02/2022  Hoses   Garden  10

02/02/2022  Rakes   Garden  12

02/02/2022  Cooking     Kitchen     14

Expected to create something like this:

[image]

##################################################################
Sorry for the inconvenience caused.
Here is the additional data and explanation:

Assume the selected date is 01/02/2022, 
 so the `TPV` column will show the 01/02/2022 data (data come from `MTD` column in the dataframe), and the `vs previous month` will show the last month data (01/01/2022).

##################################################################
I had try:

```
app.layout = dbc.Container([
                 dbc.Row([
                     dbc.Col(
                          html.Table(id= 'htmltable')
                                   )
                                 ])
                         ])

#you may ignore the date_dd , it is a date dropdown
 @app.callback(
    Output('htmltable', 'children'), 
    Input('date_dd', 'value')
    )


def update_table(selection):
    if len (selection) == 0:
        return dash.no_update

else:    
    dff = df[df['Settlement_Date'] == selection]  

    columns = dff[[Date','Minor','Major','MTD'']]


    data=columns.to_dict('records')


    table1= html.Table([
            html.Thead([
                html.Tr([
                    html.Th('Garden', id= 'Major', rowSpan = 2),
                    html.Th('TPV',id= 'MTD'),
                    html.Th('vs previous month', id= 'compare')
                    ], style = header_row_cell_style),
                
                                  
                ]),
            
            
            html.Tbody([
                
                html.Tr([
                    html.Td('Shoes', id= 'Minor',style = header_column_cell_style),
                    html.Td('',id= 'MTD'),
                    html.Td('',id= 'LMTD'),
                    ], style = body_column_cell_style),   
            
                html.Br(),

                
                html.Tr([
                    html.Td('Turf', style = header_column_cell_style),
                    html.Td('',id= 'MTD'),
                    html.Td('',id= 'LMTD'),
                    ], style = body_column_cell_style),
                
                html.Tr([
                    html.Td('Hoses', style = header_column_cell_style),
                    html.Td('',id= 'MTD'),
                    html.Td('',id= 'LMTD'),
                    ], style = body_column_cell_style),  
                                    
                html.Tr([
                    html.Td('Rakes', style = header_column_cell_style),
                    html.Td('',id= 'MTD'),
                    html.Td('',id= 'LMTD'),
                    ], style = body_column_cell_style),
                
                html.Br(),
                
                ], style = body_section_style),
            
            
            ] , style = table_style)



    return table1
```

Comment: as for me you should first use `pandas.DataFrame` to calculate expected data and later try to display it with `plotly`

Comment: Regarding the contents of the desired table, why are shoes included in the details tabulated in the `Garden`? What is the meaning of `TPV` in the column name? Is the tally a count? What does `MTD` mean in the data presented, and is it an item that needs to be output in the table?

Comment: Regarding the contents of the desired table, why are shoes included in the details tabulated in the Garden?  >>(assume there will have something which is not included in this year but included in last year's data)  What is the meaning of TPV in the column name? Is the tally a count?   >> (not tally a count, is the column name and will display the selected date' MTD data)    What does MTD mean in the data presented, and is it an item that needs to be output in the table? >> (it is represent as Month-to-date, it is a accumulated amount of sale start from the beginning of month)

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience caused. Will amend to add explanation and additional data if any.